# Beamer -- different fonts when pslatex and pdflatex are used for compilation

Tags: beamer, fonts

I have noticed that if I use either `pslatex` or `pdflatex` to compily my 
`presentation.tex` file, I get either serif or non-serif font, respectively. Why is that and how can I control that?

Comment: are you really using `pslatex` how exactly are you calling it?

Comment: ``pslatex  presentation.tex`` and then ``dvipdf   presentation.dvi``

Comment: pslatex is a simple shell script I wrote a lifetime ago that inserts the `pslatex` package into the document to use times/helvetica/courier fonts, there is no reason at all to use it this century, certainly not with beamer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pslatex` is a simple shell script that is equivalent to using `latex` with the `pslatex` package.

The `pslatex` package makes the document default to `Times/Helvetica/Courier` fonts, which will account for the font change.

`pslatex` is designed for an era in which the only available fonts were likely to be the original PostScript fonts built into a laserwriter printer, really there is no reason to use either the package or the wrapper shell script these days.

If you just use `latex` rather than `pslatex` you will get the fonts specified in the document, as for `pdflatex`.